# tkinter variable for drop down selection empty

Tags: variables, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, tkinter, ttk

I tried to program an app in tkinter that would load random lines from a file you select from a pull down menu and display the selected line in a text window.

It seems like the variable "var" in `insert_text` does not return the selected "option" but rather an "empty" string resulting in a the following error:

> "File not found error" (FileNotFoundError: [Errno2] No such file or
>   directory: '').

Please help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Python 3

import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import random

class Application:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Random Stuff')
        ttk.Frame(self.root, width=450, height=185).pack()     
        self.init_widgets()
        var = tkinter.StringVar(root)
        script = var.get()
        choices = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']
        option = tkinter.OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
        option.pack(side='right', padx=10, pady=10)              

    def init_widgets(self):
        ttk.Button(self.root, command=self.insert_txt, text='Button', width='10').place(x=10, y=10) 
        self.txt = tkinter.Text(self.root, width='45', height='5') 
        self.txt.place(x=10, y=50) 

    def insert_txt(self):
        var = tkinter.StringVar(root)
        name = var.get()
        line = random.choice(open(str(name)).readlines())
        self.txt.insert(tkinter.INSERT, line)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question! :) I saw it looked weird but when I tried to edit it it just came out like the first time I entered it. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're just creating an empty `StringVar` that isn't modified later, thus returning an empty string.

The OptionMenu takes the `command` parameter that calls the specified method every time another option is selected. Now, you can call a method like this, replacing you `insert_txt`:

```
def __init__(self):
    # ...
    self.var = tkinter.StringVar()
    self.options = tkinter.OptionMenu(root, var, *choices, command=self.option_selected)
    # ...    

def option_selected(self, event):
    name = self.var.get()
    # The stuff you already had
```

Additionally, you have to empty the `Text` widget, otherwise the previous text would stay. I think the `Entry` widget is better for that, too.

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped me a lot!!! :))) Sadly I can't upvote yet as I seem to lack the rep. :-/